# Using `esc_attr( get_block_wrapper_attributes() )`, results in `class=""wp-block-foo""`

Tags: block-editor, escaping

So, `phpcs` is telling me I need to escape the `get_block_wrapper_attributes();` function.

I thought it would be a simple as `esc_attr( get_block_wrapper_attributes() );`, but it would appear not to be the case as the output; `class=""wp-block-foo""` is not valid markup?

Is this a bug? or am I missing something? or maybe I've done something wrong... I'm not sure, so I figured I'd ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `wp_kses_data` function to escape the data. See the official Gutenberg examples repo for an [example](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/trunk/blocks-jsx/10-dynamic-block/template.php#L13)

Comment: Hi bud, nice seeing you outside the discord. In your natural habitat per se'.  Thanks for the info I'll check out the example. 